# Alternative to onChange or onBlur in jQuery dropdownchecklist control

Tags: jquery, multi-select, selectlist

Currently using the jquery dropdownchecklist found here:
http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/demo.html

I'm doing some pretty heavy processing of a large quantity of data on the client with a number of dropdownlists. Essentially, and put very simply, as each dropdown changes the data in each is filtered. I'm using the onChange event to do this but with each selection I make (I am able to make multiple selections) the event is fired, which is expected but I'm finding it's really slowing up my app. I'd much rather have the event fire when the dropdownchecklist collapses back up. I've tried using the onBlur event but this isn't happening when the div that contains the options collapses back up, only when the whole control loses focus.

Does anyone know of an event that I can use or that this control has that I can hook into to have my function fire when it collapses rather than when it changes or loses focus?

If not, how easy is it to add the functionality too it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick play and I managed to bind successfully to the blur event of the original select control.  The plugin you mentioned triggers that event when it loses focus.

```
$('#selectControl').bind('blur', function() { alert('blurred'); });
```

Are you doing it in a similar way to the above?  Can you post some code?